# Python - Aggregate multiple dataframe columns in a groupby on quarterly basis

Tags: python, pandas, time-series, pandas-groupby

I'm trying to aggregate the data based on quarterly, half yearly and yearly basis. I have a dataframe which looks like below

**Input**

```
+----+----------+-----------+----------------+--------------+---------------------+
| ID | Name     | Date      | Submission_Amt | Approved_Amt | Observation         |
+----+----------+-----------+----------------+--------------+---------------------+
| 1  | John Doe | 1/1/2019  | 100            | 90           | Exceeding Limit     |
+----+----------+-----------+----------------+--------------+---------------------+
| 1  | John Doe | 2/1/2019  | 50             | 50           | Not Exceeding Limit |
+----+----------+-----------+----------------+--------------+---------------------+
| 1  | John Doe | 3/15/2019 | 120            | 90           | Exceeding Limit     |
+----+----------+-----------+----------------+--------------+---------------------+
| 1  | John Doe | 4/2/2019  | 150            | 90           | Exceeding Limit     |
+----+----------+-----------+----------------+--------------+---------------------+
| 1  | John Doe | 5/7/2019  | 80             | 80           | Not Exceeding Limit |
+----+----------+-----------+----------------+--------------+---------------------+
| 1  | John Doe | 6/7/2019  | 50             | 40           | Not Exceeding Limit |
+----+----------+-----------+----------------+--------------+---------------------+
```

**Expected Result**

```
+----+----------+-------------------+----------------------+-----------------------+--------------------------------------+-------------------+
| ID | Name     | Period            | Total Submission Amt | Total Approved Amount | Count of Submissions exceeding Limit | Total Submissions |
+----+----------+-------------------+----------------------+-----------------------+--------------------------------------+-------------------+
| 1  | John Doe | First Half - 2019 | 560                  | 440                   | 3                                    | 5                 |
+----+----------+-------------------+----------------------+-----------------------+--------------------------------------+-------------------+
| 1  | John Doe | Q1-2019           | 420                  | 320                   | 3                                    | 4                 |
+----+----------+-------------------+----------------------+-----------------------+--------------------------------------+-------------------+
```

**Code**

So far this is the progress I've made.

```
df=df.groupby(['ID','Name','Date','Observation']).agg({'Submission_Amt':'sum','Approved_Amt':'sum'}).reset_index()
```

I was able to perform the sun() aggregation, but I was not able to do the below.

- Aggregate on quaterly basis - I tried using `groupby(.....).resample('Q')` but it didn't work.
- Aggregate and get the count of submissions and count of submissions
  which exceeded the limit.
- Aggregate for half yearly and yearly basis. I think if resample() works I can just change it to 'Y'.

Answer (score 1):

`resample` doesn't work with `groupby`. You should do something like this:

```
df.resample('Q', on='Date').agg({'Submission_Amt':'sum','Approved_Amt':'sum'}).reset_index()
```

In order to count the number of submissions exceeding limit you can pass a function in the `agg` dictionary:

```
df.resample('Q', on='Date').agg({
    'Submission_Amt':'sum',
    'Approved_Amt':'sum',
    'Observation': lambda x: x.value_counts()['Exceeding Limit']
}).reset_index()
```